# Accessing a Form's cleaned data from a signals callback?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

I've been following the tutorial from this link and it's working perfectly:

http://johnparsons.net/index.php/2013/06/28/creating-profiles-with-django-registration/

My only problem however is this line from the user_registered_callback method:

```
profile.is_human = bool(request.POST["is_human"])
```

Because it's accessing the request variable directly (if you remove the bool function).

How do I do it so the value I'm passing to my model is already validated by the referring form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form instance is not passed to this signal so I am afraid that you have to validate the data again:

```
def user_registered_callback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):

    form = ExRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    form.full_clean()

    profile = ExUserProfile(user=user)
    profile.is_human = form.cleaned_data['is_human']
    profile.save()
```

Comment: I did this but unfortunately, the is_valid() check will always return False since the username and email will be duplicates at this point.


I'm thinking, is it redundant to clean the POST variables again since, we will not get to this part of the app if they didn't pass the first validation?

Comment: You call `full_clean()` not for validation purposes. As far as I understand you don't need username/email in this callback.  You just want to get the clean value of the `is_human` field?  If yes then `form.full_clean()` do exactly what you need.  Yes, this is an ugly solution, but I don't see another way.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the form I'm extending is not a ModelForm. It seems that full_clean is only available for Model Forms.

Comment: Nope. `full_clean()` is the method of the `forms.BaseForm()` class so it exists in every django form instance.

Comment: Thanks catavaran it worked! Wonder why it's not mentioned in the Form documentation.

Comment: Actually this is mentioned in the first paragraph of the form validation docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Oh that's why I couldn't see it. I was looking at the wrong place. Again Thank You!